# Is there a way to script a mass update of yaml files in Azure Repos

Tags: python, git, azure, azure-devops, yaml

My company recently migrated a large project from TFS to GIT and while the migration is over we have about 40 repos that need the yaml file updated, we broke up the project into a bunch of repos. During the initial migration we had a boilerplate yaml we added in manually but it was very bare bones.

Through trial and error we came up with a pipeline that would work for each repo but I was wondering if there was a way to mass update the yaml files in these repos to save time, I'm also pretty sure there will be tweaks made to the pipelines and I don't really want to update each yaml manually every time.

I looked into the Azure CLI but don't believe that has what I'm looking for. I'm relatively new to Azure DevOps and wanted to know if there was a tool or plugin that already does this and if not has anyone come across an example of a script that did something similar?

Thanks for any help you can give.

Comment: I've written a thing for this, but it doesn't support azure git repos yet (would be a pretty straightforward PR to add support for it): https://github.com/asottile/all-repos

Comment: Thanks! I may use this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After doing a lot of googling and talking with an SRE from another team I'm going to solve this via templates.

I'm going to create a central repository for scripts, yaml templates, etc. and then put a very basic pipeline in each repository that basically passes in parameters and that's it. That way any global changes I make I can just make the change to the template.

Not 100% the way I wanted to solve it but it will fix most of my issues.